# Azure Mobile App Service Role Authorization Not Working

Tags: entity-framework, azure, authentication, owin, azure-mobile-services

Using above service with Xamarin form, I have enable authentication with OAuth (Microsoft and Google). API call are working fine and those functions with [Authorize], are being enforced with authentication.

However, when defining specific role, it returns 401 error. I'm trying to create my own attribute from  *AuthorizationFilterAttribute* class.

I'm storing the user info and roles in my custom tables : **UserProfile** and **UserRoles**. Hence, I'm not sure where to define these. Since its not reading data from these tables. If I try to run following, it returns empty result.

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Roles()
    {
        ClaimsIdentity claimsId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
        var appRoles = new List<String>();
        foreach (Claim claim in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindAll(claimsId.RoleClaimType))
            appRoles.Add(claim.Value);

        return Ok(appRoles);
    }
```

The closest article I came across in based on Web API : [Web Api 2 and Owin](http://www.azurefromthetrenches.com/how-to-register-and-authenticate-with-web-api-2-and-owin)

**Edit** Based on answer by Adrian, I added following code, but yet getting same 401 error.

```
public class MyAuthorize : System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    private string[] accessRoleNames;

    public MyAuthorize(params string[] roleNames)
    {
        accessRoleNames = roleNames;
    }

    public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
           OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        WMSEntities db = new WMSEntities();

        string userID = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name;
        var user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.User_ID == userID);

        if (user == null)
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        else
        {
            bool ok = false;
            foreach (var item in user.AppRoles)
            {
                foreach (string ar in accessRoleNames)
                {
                    if (item.Name == ar)
                        ok = true;
                }
            }
            db.Dispose();

            if (!ok)
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }
}
```

And referencing to my function as follows :

```
    [MyAuthorize(UserRole.Admin, UserRole.Collector)]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetDataAdmin")]
    public string GetDataAdmin()
    {
        return "success access GetDataAdmin";
    }
```

If I debug the code locally, the OnAuthorization events are not being hit , hence not sure how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Azure Mobile Apps, you are using EntityFramework.  You can do any query you want to this.  Here is an example AuthorizationFilterAttribute that checks claims returned by an AAD credential:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Server.Authentication;

namespace Backend.Helpers
{
    public class AuthorizeClaimsAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        string Type { get; }
        string Value { get; }

        public AuthorizeClaimsAttribute(string type, string value)
        {
            Type = type;
            Value = value;
        }

        public override async Task OnAuthorizationAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var request = actionContext.Request;
            var user = actionContext.RequestContext.Principal;
            if (user != null)
            {
                var identity = await user.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<AzureActiveDirectoryCredentials>(request);
                var countOfMatchingClaims = identity.UserClaims
                    .Where(c => c.Type.Equals(Type) && c.Value.Equals(Value))
                    .Count();
                if (countOfMatchingClaims > 0) return;

            }
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
    }
}
```

This particular version allows you to do things like:

```
[AuthorizeClaims("groups","some-object-id")]
```

You can use this as a model.  Where I check the `GetAppServiceIdentityAsync()`, you can check your database instead and decide whether the principal has a role.

Comment: I tried above, but no luck either. Still getting 401 error, and I can't debug it locally since the event is not being hit.

Comment: Some correction in my code and it works :



     var identity = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            Claim identityClaim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            
            var user = db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.User_ID.EndsWith(identityClaim.Value));'